# Magento: Order Total different from Invoice Total

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Probably I am not perfect with magento. 
But till today everything worked perfectly.

Now we faced a problem.

Grand Total inside sales order is defferent from the invoices one and I cannot process authorization.

Please see attached pictures, and let me know if there is any suggestions how to fix that.

It seems like inside invoice shipping adds to the grand total, but it doesn't have to, bcause inside order all calculations are correct.

Please see attached images here: http://goo.gl/nWAJQu

Comment: What is the code you have that's generating this? Which specific numbers are off, and what do you expect them to be?

Comment: Please see attached images here: http://goo.gl/nWAJQu

Comment: It seems like shipping adds one more time to grand total when invoicing. We set up the deposit/discount so the customer will be able to pay just 10% from the order and pay the rest amount on delivery with cash.

Comment: Ok, so you have some images. Is one of these the one that's good, and the other that's bad? Which numbers, specifically, are not what you expect, and what do you expect them to be? Also, what is the code that generates this total?

Comment: @zck - that's the problem... we don't have specialist at this moment and i think i would be able to fix it, if i knew where the code is generated for invoicing.The picture which shows $24.32 is correct one, but when i try to send order for invoice - it generates $54.32... which seems to be +$30 from shipping...

Comment: In that case, what answer are you looking for from Stack Overflow? You already know that the grand total of the second one is adding the shipping in twice, or adding it to the grand total. So without seeing code, I'm not sure what else I can do to help you out.